# Android: add clicklistener on ImageView inside a CardView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

On my RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(WorkoutViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
  ....
  viewHolder.mCreatorAvatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "AVATAR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

On my Fragment parent which contains the RecyclerView:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
        new RecyclerItemClickListener(BrowseSessionsFragment.this.getActivity(),
                mRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                // do whatever
                Toast.makeText(BrowseSessionsFragment.this.getActivity(), "ITEM" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

The problem is: when I click on ImageView there are 2 messages: 
ITEMx then AVATAR; how to fire just AVATAR message in this case?

Thanks guys!

Comment: you should remove the `addOnItemTouchListener`

Comment: Not ! Because I want to prevent when the card is click to do a treatment after.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to OnItemClickListener for RecyclerView you must create your own interface, such as

```
public interface OnItemClick {
       void onItemClick(int position);
}
```

And after that just implement it in your activity/fragment and set it to adapter.
In adapter set OnClickListener for element, that you need in your ViewHolder and give position of list item to your interface, e.g.

```
static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
ImageView mCreatorAvatar;

public ViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClick onItemClick) {
super(itemView);
//...some code...
mCreatorAvatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if(onItemClick != null){
                  onItemClick.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
               }
            }
       }
}
```

And in activity/fragment that implements interface OnItemClick

```
public void onItemClick(int position) {
      //do smth
}
```

If you want to receive the click's on the full list item just set  with similar way second OnItemClick to the itemView in your ViewHolder

Comment: The problem is the same Viktor.

Comment: @anthony you should remove OnItemTouchListener and set OnItemClick to the itemView in the adapter.

Comment: Actually, I want to allow : click on the complete item (done with OnItemTouchListener), and click on just avatar imageview.

Comment: @anthony you can allow it with two OnItemClick: first for itemView(its for complete item click) and second for avatar imageview